# Прогрессбар на секундах с бордером на блоке

Tags: vue.js

Как реализовать "прогрессбар" на 90 секунд с `border`, который будет обозначать сколько секунд закончилось. Если 90 вышло - значит `border` заполнен полностью по кругу. `Border` заполнения можно реализовать красный

```css
.modal-timer__loader-circle {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        background: #E4F5FD;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 10px solid #DBF1FB;
    }
    
    .modal-timer__loader-title{
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 29px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #6654A4;
        padding-top: 28px;
        margin: 0px 8px;
    }
    .modal-timer__loader-seconds {
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 29px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #63C587;
        flex: none;
        order: 1;
        flex-grow: 0;
        margin: 0px 8px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="modal-timer__loader">
        <div class="modal-timer__loader-circle">
            924892347
        </div>
        <div class="modal-timer__loader-title">
            {{'СODE'}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-timer__loader-seconds">
            00:90
        </div>
        <button
            class="button-done"
            type="main"
            data-test="withdraw-submit"
        >
            {{ 'Done' }}
        </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать анимацию заполнения круга можно воспользоваться `SVG`, в частности тегом [circle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle) и парочкой атрибутов: [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) и [stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset).

Все остальное это легкие математические операции и все.

Это простой вариант с анимацией на `CSS`, вариант анимации на `JS` с помощью [lerp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) будет выглядеть получше, но это самый-самый простой вариант.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        total_seconds: 10,
        seconds_left: 10,
        interval_id: null,
        complete: false,
        
        circle_path_length: 0,
    },
    computed: {
        seconds() {
            return this.seconds_left.toString().padStart(2, '0');
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const circleElement = this.$refs.circle;
        this.circle_path_length = circleElement.getTotalLength();
        circleElement.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', this.circle_path_length);
        circleElement.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', this.circle_path_length);

        this.start();
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval_id);
    },
    methods: {
        start() {
            if (this.interval_id) return;

            this.complete = false;
            this.seconds_left = this.total_seconds;
            this.interval_id = setInterval(this.update, 1000);
        },
        update() {
            this.seconds_left--;
            if (this.seconds_left < 1) this.finish();

            const percent = this.total_seconds / this.seconds_left;
            const path_length = this.circle_path_length / percent;
            this.$refs.circle.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', path_length);
        },
        finish() {
            clearInterval(this.interval_id);
            this.interval_id = null;
            this.complete = true;
        }
    }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
}

#app {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 35%;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

svg circle {
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke: #2980b9;
    stroke-width: 10;
    fill: #3498db;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

svg circle.complete {
    stroke: #27ae60;
    fill: #2ecc71;
}

svg text {
    fill: #fff;
    font-size: 35px;
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: central;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#app button {
    border: 10px solid #f39c12;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transition: all .2s;
}

#app button.complete {
    border: 10px solid #9b59b6;
    background-color: #8e44ad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle
            ref="circle"
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="45"
            :class="{ complete }"
        />
        <text x="50" y="50">{{ seconds }}</text>
    </svg>
    <button @click="start" :class="{ complete }">START</button>
</div>
```